# How to query parse php sdk get all key of ParseRelation?

Tags: php, parse-platform

I have 2 tables `tblAlbum` and `tblProduction`, the album has a relation with `tblProduction`. 
(album_title, album_id, production(kind of ParseRelation),...)

I want to write a query to get the album including all the production keys?
Like this (album_title, album_id, production_name, production_title,...)

Note - I am using Parse PHP SDK.

Comment: anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have `production` setup as a **pointer** or a **relation**, but I'll elaborate on both here for you.

As a **pointer** (1-1) you would need only adjust your query like so.

```
$query = new ParseQuery('Album');

// include the nested object under 'production'
$query->includeKey('production');

// get albums with Production set under 'production'
$albums = $query->find();
```

As a **relation** (1-many) you would need to make a *separate* query to get all the associated `production` objects.

```
$relation = $albums->getRelation('production'); // can add Production as the class name as 2nd arg if you have issues
$relationQuery = $relation->getQuery();

// get all Production objects
$productions = $relationQuery->find();
```

If you're continually making this relation query for each `Album` you can reduce your overhead down to about 2 queries. Just add a pointer in `Production` going back to it's parent `Album` and use `ParseQuery::orQueries` to join *all* your relation queries into one convenient query.

```
// get albums
$query = new ParseQuery('Album');
$albums = $query->find();

// get each relation query for each album
$queries = [];
foreach($albums as $album) {
    $relation = $album->getRelation('production', 'Production');
    $queries[] = $relation->getQuery();
}

// combine your relation queries
$query = ParseQuery::orQueries($queries);

// include the parent 'album' pointer so we can
// sort which objects belong where
$query->includeKeys('album');

// get these productions
$productions = $query->find();
```

You could also do some stuff with `matchesKeyInQuery`, but I would encourage you to read up on the [docs](http://docs.parseplatform.org/php/guide/#queries) to get some details on that.